# How to align text dynamically inside a rectangle with Phaser JS

Tags: text, phaser

I am just starting to learn the Phaser JS framework with my first game. I did not managed to find a way how i can align text inside a rectangle element dynamically without specific coordinates. Here is what i have

```
pointH11L1 = game.add.text(0, 0, '20'); 
pointH11L1.stroke = "#000";
pointH11L1.strokeThickness = 4;
pointH11L1.font = 'oswaldbold';
pointH11L1.fontSize = 22;
pointH11L1.fill = '#999999';
//pointH11L1.alignIn(graphicsRectH12L2, Phaser.CENTER);
graphicsRectH12L2.addChild(pointH11L1);
pointH11L1.x = pointH11L1.width / 2 - 6; 
pointH11L1.y = -2.5;
```

//graphicsRectH12L2 is the  rectangle inside which i need to align.

```
var graphicsRectH12L2 = this.game.add.graphics(950, 405); 
    graphicsRectH12L2.beginFill(0xffcd00, 1);
    graphicsRectH12L2.drawRect(0, 0, 44, 29);
    graphicsRectH12L2.endFill(0xffcd00, 1);
    group.add(graphicsRectH12L2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended the Phaser.Graphics and added a Phaser.Text inside it, and center the text inside the graphics, like so:

```
var textStyle = {
    font: "normal 24px Arial",
    fill: '#ffffff',
    align: 'center',
    boundsAlignH: "center", // bounds center align horizontally
    boundsAlignV: "middle" // bounds center align vertically
};
var textElement = new Phaser.Text(game, 0, 0, "Hello World", textStyle);
var graphics = new Phaser.Graphics(game, 0, 0);

// graphics and textElement bounds/sizes must be the same
// so your text area covers the whole rectangle
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 100);
textElement.setTextBounds(0, 0, 400, 100);

graphics.addChild(textElement);
game.world.addChild(graphics);

// That's it! Now the text should be centered horizontally and vertically
// in the graphics element
```